# Problemas com codigo de uma lista de prioridade em C

Tags: c, c++, algoritmo

Estou criando uma lista de prioridade em C (ordenação topológica) usando vetores e dentro desses vetores uma lista encadeada apontando quem tem que vir antes de quem. Só que está dando erro no ponteiro e eu realmente não consigo entender.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define DIM 50

typedef struct list{
    struct list * prox;
    int contador;
}LISTA;

typedef struct ant{
    struct ant* prox;
    int chave;
}PRE;

void iniciar(int n, int m, LISTA lista[DIM], PRE *ptpre);

int main(void){
    LISTA lista[DIM],pt;
    PRE ptpre;

    int m,n,fim,objeto,indice,i;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);
    iniciar(n,m,lista,&ptpre);
    fim = 0;
    lista[0].contador=0;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
        if(lista[i].contador==0){
            lista[fim].contador = i;
            fim = i;
        } 
    }
    objeto=lista[0].contador;
    while(objeto != 0){
        printf("%d",objeto);
        pt = lista[objeto].prox;
        while (*pt != 0){
            indice = pt->chave;
            lista[indice].contador = lista[indice].contador -1;
            if (lista[indice].contador == 0){
                lista[fim].contador = indice;
                fim = indice;
            }
            pt = pt->prox;
        }
      objeto=lista[objeto].contador; 
    }
return 0;    
}

void iniciar(int n, int m, LISTA lista[DIM], PRE *ptpre){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=n;i++){
        lista[i].contador = 0;
        lista[i].prox = 0;
    }
    for (i=1;1<=m;i++){
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
        ptpre = (PRE *) malloc(sizeof(PRE));
        ptpre -> chave = b;
        ptpre -> prox = lista[a].prox;
        lista[a].prox = ptpre;
        lista[b].contador = lista[b].contador + 1;
    }


}
```

Comment: Pode mostrar o erro?

Comment: source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
source_file.c:36:12: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘LISTA {aka struct list}’ from type ‘struct list *’
         pt = lista[objeto].prox;

Answer (score 0):

Em

```
LISTA lista[DIM],pt;
```

você está criando pt como uma variável `LISTA`, e não como um **ponteiro** para uma variável `LISTA`. Por isso você não pode passar `lista[objeto].prox` para pt, pois `prox` é um **ponteiro** e `pt` é uma variável qualquer. Para corrigir este problema, mude a declaração de pt para

```
LISTA lista[DIM], *pt;
```

Também percebi outros erros no seu código, como tentar acessar uma variável `chave` dentro do struct `pt`. Isso é impossível, porque `pt` é uma `LISTA`, e o único **struct** no seu código que tem um membro chamado `chave` é o **struct** `PRE`.

Comment: Ola amigo, eu fiz as alterações que vc disse. mudei de *pt para *ptpre so que o problema que ta dando é na hora de criar um ponteiro que aponte para a propria estrutura. da erro dizendo que o tipo do ponteiro *ptpre é diferente do ponteiro da estrutura so que nao faz sentido ja que o *ptpre é do mesmo tipo da estrutura que quero apontar